# What's wrong with my structure data?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

It's been more than 4 months that our rich snippets suddenly disappeared, some error were reported in GWT, i corrected everything and errors are now decreasing (only 5 left). here is my code:

```
<section class="c-center" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div>
        <h1><span itemprop="name">Product name</span> <span itemprop="brand" class="brand"><a href="/link-to-brand/">Brand of product</a></span></h1>
        <div id="reviews" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
            <div class="rating">
                <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.8" />
                <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="56" />
                <div class="fill" style="width:96%"></div>
                <div class="stars"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="rating-info">
                <a href="#ratings-reviews">Based on 56 reviews</a> - <a href="#">Write a review</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="img">
        <img src="/link-to-image.jpg" alt="Img alt" itemprop="image" />
    </div>

    <div id="info">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="site.com/link-of-product/">
        <div id="price-container" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR">
            <meta itemprop="gtin13" content="1234567899999">
            <span class="price" itemprop="price">19,95 €</span> <del>28,50 €</del> -
            <span class="stock"><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">Available</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

here are my questions:
1- is there anything wrong? 
2- I've seen in many posts that currency should not be in the `itemprop="price"` but in google examples, they do include it! what should I do? 
3- should I use `ratingCount` or `reviewCount` ? 
4- some products exist in different sizes with different prices, is it recommended to include the `AggregateOffer` with lowest and highest price?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

How does it appear visually?

The [structured data linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/) shows a typical snippet which looks good and has star rating, and there are no errors in google's tool. Two things which stand out are:

- url has no protocol, set to http://yoursite.com/page1 for
- price should be number only, which could well be affecting search results, currency is a separate field so should not be embedded in price as well
- use `<meta>` to give your price with a full stop as the separator, not the comma and put large values as 1234567.89 not 1,234,567.89 or 1.234.567,89 but display it as you would normally

> `price` info from http://schema.org/
>
> Use the priceCurrency property (with ISO 4217 codes e.g. "USD") instead of including ambiguous symbols such as '$' in the value.
>
> Use '.' (Unicode 'FULL STOP' (U+002E)) rather than ',' to indicate a decimal point. Avoid using these symbols as a readability separator.
>
> Note that both RDFa and Microdata syntax allow the use of a "content=" attribute for publishing simple machine-readable values alongside more human-friendly formatting.
>
> Use values from 0123456789 (Unicode 'DIGIT ZERO' (U+0030) to 'DIGIT NINE' (U+0039)) rather than superficially similiar Unicode symbols.

google actually gives this example in its [policies page](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies)

```
<span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span><span itemprop="price">119.99</</span>
```

- previous Offer price, you could include in `<del>` structured data for the expired Offer price, with priceValidUntil set to a date in the past, the current price can also have an expiry date.
- consider setting `itemCondition` to http://schema.org/NewCondition
- image urls - I've noticed that full url starting path rather than a relative path seem to be preferred - your `/link-to-image.jpg` is interpreted as `http://example.com/link-to-image.jpg` not `http://site. com/link-to-image.jpg` in the testing tool, I'm unsure if this is the same when testing direct from the URL but it seems best not to be amigous
- lastly use a shopping search tool, including google shopping to search for a best seller, see if it can find it by price, brand, availability etc. if competitor sites appear first you can even check the structured data tester with their URL to see if you are missing anything

Comment: Thanks Mousey for your detailed reply.
Actually nothing appears for the moment, it disappeared about 4 or 5 months ago!! :/
OK for the price tag, i'll separate the currency and price itself.
and what about question 3 & 4 ? :)
Thanks

Comment: q3 if you want stars in the snippets and they are ratings not text reviews use ratingCount. If you have full reviews,  use reviewCount too. Details are on http://schema.org/AggregateRating - as you can see in the structured data linter the stars appear, so it look correct. Check the linter and google structured data tester with your URL to make sure the data is recognized.  q4- there is no aggregate for offers as far as I know,  nest the high and low price inside with the `itemprop="offers"` property. Changes normally show 3-4 days after manually re-fetch a page, if not check for syntax errors

Comment: Actually the linter shows stars whith both ratingCount and reviewCount, that's why i was wondering which one should be used! <br>
Regarding the aggregate offers, i saw it on this page: [link](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products)
i have manually fetched different URLs, but they still dont show within google results page :( the syntax and all the code is correct. I now have only 2 errors left on GWT, i'll wait until i have no more errors and hope all will get back to normal!

Comment: reviewCount expects a text review as well I think. AggregateOffer is new to me, a more specific version of Offer, so it sounds idea for what you want. What does the google structured data tester show from *your url*? If this is missing data then you won't get an error in GWT. I've noticed before that things like mispelled schema or property names mean it gives no error but missed out the data. If every piece does not appear in google's tester then there is a problem, maybe higher up.

Comment: The google structured data tester shows "All is good". I'm now using AggregateOffer, but i'm still confused about so many things: 1- should I also use highPrice? 2- if only one product available, should I use Offer instead of AggregateOffer? or just set highPrice and google will understand that i have only one product available? 3- in the AggregateOffer example, they don't use availability, isn't it an important information anymore? the whole thing about AggregateOffer sounds great but not very clear!!

Comment: 1.AggregateOffer gives you a choice of 3 prices -  `price`, `lowPrice` and `highPrice` - use `price` if that item has a single price and ignore the others. 
2. there is no `price` or `highPrice` inside http://schema.org/Product so you will need to use either `highPrice`/`lowPrice` from http://schema.org/AggregateOffer or `price` from http://schema.org/Offer - both should work but the latter is the closest semantically AggregateOffer is really for several of the same product at different prices, eg one is Used, one is New - or both are New but `highPrice` is from supplier1, `lowPrice` Supplier2

Comment: 3- AggregateOffer is a more specific type of `Offer` which means it inherits **every** field that Offer has, just scroll down and you will see `availability` is there, so is `price` not just low/high prices. The examples use `itemCount` for a number in stock rather than just In http://schema.org/inStock http://schema.org/outOfStock. It's up to search engines which fields they check for someone is searching for items in stock, they may search only availability, or may search itemCount >0 too. It feels a 'safer' idea to include inStock but if you do mostly bulk orders itemCount might be best

Comment: Examples don't use every field, so don't worry about adding what  is not in examples. Search engines may only use a minority of the fields, so key things like prices, product names and brands will get you the majority of the results in structured data. The schema does not affect what is shown once the person is on the page - as far as I know the web browsers don't highlight schema fields, only search engines do.

Comment: OK thanks for your in-lights....
I'm still depressed, no stars and rich snippets appear on google result page :/ however if i enter site:domain.com product_name, it shows the stars, do you know why?

Comment: it might not have caught up with your changes yet? It might depend on if you search google.com or local versions like fr.google.com (France), it sounds like google is showing a cached version. Try Fetch as google &  submit to index for a specific page that shows the stars in sitelinks. It takes up to 3 days on my site to appear in search results after that. Check that page is in your sitemap and is not excluding robots too.

Comment: I have just fetched and submitted one page, i'll see the results within 3 or 4 days and will let you know ;)

Comment: @Websphere how are the results now?

Comment: Hi, wow, I was just thinking about you few days ago and wanted to want a little longer to be sure. The stars still don't appear in google results :( I'll wait more and see!

Comment: if you've re-crawel already then waiting won't help, change all relative paths for your `<a href` links to the full path including sitename and recrawl, it seems to not always pick up relative paths, check the structured data linter's preview shows the stars in the ratings too (GWT doesn't preview) do a visual preview), you'll need to double-check your for any disallowing of robots too

Comment: Actually I didn't recrawl by myself, but goggle did! How can I trigger the recrawl?? The structured data linter shows the stars correctly, but Google doesn't :( I still have 4 errors in gwt, I'll wait until they disappear than maybe google will start displaying the stars... :) and in robots.txt, I'm only disallowing query strings (Disallow /*?*)

Comment: in google webmaster tools, go to Crawl then Fetch as Google

Comment: Hi @Mousey, how are you? Just wanted to let you know the stars finally started to show up on google results, after more than 6 months... :D thanks for all ;)